# CSS grid template with full width row

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create 2 columns template that converts to 1 column for lower resolution devices. This is what I have done so far

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 800px));
  grid-gap: 30px;
}


.item {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJZeeX 
When i scale down resolution it changes to one column but theres so much space left on the right side. I would like the .item divs to take whole space available. plus I would like to avoid using @media query. I was thinking maybe I should combine CSS grid with flexbox somehow? But not really sure if that would lead anywhere. Thank you

Comment: There's empty space on the right side because you have a `max-width: 800px` on the columns. So when the screen size exceeds the max, there will be a gap. If you don't need the 800px, replace it with `1fr`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrYNWN

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best shot.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 30px;

}


.item {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```